# C++ how do I do exception handling for switch case

Tags: c++

If user key in letter like "a" , it will result in endless loop, the default: doesnt work.

How do i do exception handling so its will output error message instead of endless loop.

Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
done=false;
do
{
cout << "Please select the department: " << endl;
cout << "1. Admin " << endl;
cout << "2. HR " << endl;
cout << "3. Normal " << endl;
cout << "4. Back to Main Menu " << endl;
cout << "Selection: ";
cin >> choice;



switch (choice) {
  case 1:
      department_selection = "admin";
    done=true;
    break;
  case 2:
      department_selection = "hr";
    done=true;
    break;
  case 3:
      department_selection = "normal";
    done=true;
    break;
  case 4:
      selection = "hr_menu";
    done=true;
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Invalid selection - Please input 1 to 3 only.";
    done=false;
        }
}while(done!=true);
```

Comment: the problem is because you wait for int (i think) when you get a char it's an error and it won't be caught at the default try to check first that you got int only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't your switch statement but the fact that you don't check if input operation actually succeeded. Always use input operations in some boolean context:

```
int choice = 0;
while (!(cin >> choice) && (choice < 1 || choice > 4)) {
    cout << "Invalid selection - Please input 1 to 3 only.\n";
    // reset error flags
    cin.clear();
    // throw away garbage input
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // the above two statements prevent infinite loop due to
    // bad stream state
}

// proceed to switch statement
```

`numeric_limits` template is located in `<limits>` header.

Comment: what library i need to use for numeric_limits , i got some error client.cpp:2552:16: error: ‘numeric_limits’ was not declared in this scope
client.cpp:2552:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
client.cpp:2552:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘max()’
client.cpp:2552:48: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:210:5: note: template<class _Tp> const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:254:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Compare> const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare)